# Spring Boot REST Controller is not parsing the given Json parameter to Java object

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, converters

Using Spring Boot, I want to build a Rest controller. But Spring fails to convert Json to Java object automatically. And yes:

- I have empty constructors
- I tried @RequestParam, @RequestBody, @RequestPart
- My JSON parameter is valid (I tried to parse with Gson, and it worked)

Here is my REST Controller:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

     @RequestMapping(value= "/abc", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
     public @ResponseBody MyResponse handlePurchase(@RequestParam A request){
         return new MyResponse("Simply the best");
     }

}
```

Here is A.java:

```
public class A implements Serializable {

    private B something;

    public B getSomething() {
        return Something;
    }

    public void setSomething(B something) {
        this.Something = something;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A [Something=" + something + "]";
    }

    public A(B something) {
        super();
        this.Something = something;
    }

    public A() {
        super();
    }


}
```

Here is B.java which is used by A.java:

```
public class B implements Serializable {
    private String something;
    private int catsNumber;
    private int dogsNumber;

    public String getSomething() {
        return something;
    }

    public void setSomething(String something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

    public int getCatsNumber() {
        return catsNumber;
    }

    public void setCatsNumber(int catsNumber) {
        this.catsNumber = catsNumber;
    }

    public int getDogsNumber() {
        return dogsNumber;
    }

    public void setDogsNumber(int dogsNumber) {
        this.dogsNumber = dogsNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B [something=" + something + ", catsNumber=" + catsNumber + ", dogsNumber=" + dogsNumber + "]";
    }

    public B() {
        super();
    }


}
```

Hope someone can help me on this, neither worked yet:

- Spring.io
- other Stackoverflow Q&As

Comment: Do you have any exception ?

Comment: Can you share your message body json?

Comment: can you post your pom.xml

Comment: @kuhajeyan: posted

Comment: can you change to
@RequestMapping(value= "/abc", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 

and instead of \@RequestParam use \@RequestBody

Comment: Yeah, thanks, working for me

Answer (score 2):

`@RequestParam` indicates an url parameter `http://foo.com?parameter=x`. When using post, you need to define a `@RequestBody`

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/abc", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody MyResponse handlePurchase(@RequestBody A a){
     return new MyResponse("Simply the best");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not working at all (Before changing the "@RequestParam" to "@RequestBody", posting worked well for me): 

Here's what I get for posting (www-form-urlencoded)

    {
      "timestamp": 1470992850627,
      "status": 415,
      "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
      "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
      "message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
      "path": "/purchase"
    }

Comment: And the simple form-data:"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
      "message": "Could not read document: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@478e62db; line: 1, column: 3]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@478e62db; line: 1, column: 3] ... }

Comment: What tool are you using to generate you post? Can you share your application (github/bitbucket/...)

Comment: @Janekx - Set the Content-Type to application/json while posting your request

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten, but that is also set.

Comment: It is difficult helping you, if you only provide limited code snippets. Can you provide the JSON that you are posting?

Comment: @JohanB: I've posted almost all the codes which this project consist of. I'm posting the following:

Comment: key: a
value: 

{
  "something": {
    "something": "Hey apple",
    "catsNumber": 1,
    "dogsNumber": 1
  }
}